# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 Memory Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory, sql-server-express, out-of-memory

I have a website running on a Windows 2008 R2 server, using a SQL Server Express 2008 R2 database, and I have been experiencing some pretty nasty memory issues the last several days.

Here's the server stats:

- It's a Rackspace Cloud Server
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 x64
- Quad-Core AMD Opteron 2.34GHz
- 2GB RAM
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition with Advanced Services x64
- Full text indexing is being used

The website has been running good for a few months now, but all of a sudden I've been seeing errors related to SQL Server running out of memory.  Here are the most common exceptions I've seen:

> Warning: Fatal error 9001 occurred at Oct 22 2011 5:02AM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.

---

> There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

---

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

---

> Error: 4060, Severity: 11, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped. Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

---

> Error: 3980, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.

The website still seems to respond for the most part.  The pages that seem to be affected the most are the ones that write to the database.

I have tried restarting the sqlexpress service as well as restarting the server.  Both solutions fix the symptoms, but the problem comes back within about 10 to 15 hours.

When these errors occur, Task Manager reports that around 1.8GB of memory is being used.  After I restart the service, the used memory drops back down to about 600MB used and very slowly climbs backup until the exceptions start showing up again.

All help will be greatly appreciated... thanks!

Comment: Please contact me at marco.marsala AT live.it to see if our solution is applicable in your case to definitely solve the root cause of this annoying issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ERRORLOG will contain some important information about the memory allocation pattern when things started to degrade. The lines will look similar to this:

```
  MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL (node 1)                                  KB 
   ---------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
   VM Reserved                                                      0
   VM Committed                                                     0
   AWE Allocated                                                    0
   SM Reserved                                                      0
   SM Commited                                                      0
   SinglePage Allocator                                             136
   MultiPage Allocator                                              0

   (7 row(s) affected)
```

Search your ERRORLOG files for such occurrences, the follow the guidance from [How to use the DBCC MEMORYSTATUS command to monitor memory usage on SQL Server 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877), since the output of DBCC MEMORYSTATUS and the output in the ERRORLOG due to OOM status is quite similar.

Comment: I found one of the occurrences, but I'm still not sure what I'm looking for.  I read that MEMORYSTATUS link you gave me, but I'm still not sure what I'm looking for.  I've uploaded an excerpt from the ERRORLOG here if you'd like to take a look: http://db.tt/Jv3y643t

Let me know if you see any red flags.  Thanks!

Comment: MEMORYCLERK_FULLTEXT is consuming 963840 Kb. What is the status of `sys.dm_fts_memory_buffers` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180044.aspx ? According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142560.aspx, your 2Gb is awfully inadequate.

Comment: Thanks! I was already pretty much already planning on increasing the amount of RAM on that server. I'm just not sure that will solve this problem or if it will just cause it to take a little longer for the memory to run out.

As for the `sys.dm_fts_memory_buffers`, I just ran a select query on it, and came up with zero rows. I'll try running it again when the errors start coming in.

Comment: You should run the query when the system is low on memory. But it may still return 0, menaing no FT index build operation is in progress.

Comment: I've been keeping an eye on the system, but of course the out of memory problems aren't showing up anymore. I'm still going to increase the memory in the system anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have 4GB on the server now, but the OOM errors have returned.  It looks like the errors are not related to the amount of RAM on the system, but the amount of RAM that SQL Server Express is allowed to use.  The errors are now occurring when the system has 2GB of free memory (SQL is using about 1GB, which is the max for Express).

Comment: The final solution seems to be to switch the full text indexing to Manual Change Tracking, and then occasionally initiate the incremental index by hand.  Seems like a ridiculous solution since SQL Server supposedly provides an automatic way to do it, but it works and my OOM errors have gone away completely.

Comment: Here at Network Solution we had a long day with this issue, and finally we expertise and solved this specific error (Fatal Error 9001) at server configuration level.

Result of our work is a shared server where newly created DB are 9001-free thanks to our config scripts (made in years of expertise), preconfigured with the SessionState DB, the ideal for Windows-IIS-ASP.NET-MSSQL shared hosting!